# Firefox extension to handle too many tabs open on Android

Tags: android, firefox

I have a habit of leaving tabs open for 'reading later' on my mobile.  This is a bad habit, since it now means I have 100+ tabs open.  The problem is that the tab view in Firefox for Android truncates the titles of the tabs, so I often can't tell which ones I can close.  Is there an extension that will let me see the full titles of the tabs and close them easily?  Or a way to sync the tab list / close tabs from my desktop?